# Connect a MacBook pro M1 pro, a PC with VGA and DVI output and a PS5 to 2 Displays with USB C DP and HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi, usb-c

Here is the List of devices with supported outputs:

- MacBook pro M1 pro: 3 USB-C and 1 HDMI output
- PC: 1 VGA and 1 DVI output
- PS5: 1 HDMI output

Here is the Displays I have:

- DELL P3223QE: 1 USB-C, 1 HDMI, 1 DP input
- DELL P2723DE: 1 USB-C, 1 HDMI, 1 DP input

Requirments:

- Macbook Pro should be connected to both of displays and one of the connections should be USB-C to use the docking capability of one of the monitors (for charging, Ethernet, ...)
- PS5 should be connected to the 32" Monitor
- PC should be connected preferably to both of displays but at least to 32" one

I could also buy some adapters/cables if necessary. Any idea how to connect these devices to the displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect up with what you hopefully already own [presumably the displays came supplied with these]; preferably the USB-Cs from the Mac, HDMI from the PS5, leaving you needing to buy a DVI>DP cable [example from google, these are not reversible](https://www.cdw.com/product/startech.com-dvi-to-displayport-adapter-usb-power-dvi-d-to-dp-converter/4888592#:%7E:text=to%20DisplayPort%20monitor-,Use%20this%20DVI%20to%20DisplayPort%20converter%20to%20connect%20your%20DVI,(DP)%20monitor%20or%20projector.) which needs additional USB2 power.

I'd be surprised if the PC's GPU will support 2 displays at once, with those connectors as the only options. DVI>DP will only achieve 1920x1200 [or 1920x1080 on a 16:9 display.] Plus, if you can ever actually find one, a VGA>anything digital would cost more than a new GPU. The DVI>DP is already about the price of a low-end modern card with 2 DP ports.

Comment: This would obviously work. But I decided to do it a bit differently. I ordered a second hand Graphic card with DP and HDMI output for 40€. this would be cheaper and needs no adapters.